# Is it ok to fly with a snowman?

Tags: air-travel, helsinki

Will I be facing any problems carrying a snowman on the airplane?
The kids & I are going to Helsinki next month and I expect my little ones to make their first snowman. I would like to keep that souvenir. If I stick it in a cooler can I carry it with me on the plane?

We'll be coming back home to London with [SAS](https://www.flysas.com/en/uk/)

Comment: You should definitly start a blog and show the outcome of that along the years :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you freeze liquids to pass security checks?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27302/can-you-freeze-liquids-to-pass-security-checks)

Comment: @davidvc disagree, I think the snowman deserves to have its own seat reserved aboard.

Comment: Shows a lack of prior research vis: basic physics, aircraft environmental conditions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's really a joke.

Comment: Sorry, but Frosty will have to travel as hold luggage.

Comment: I propose to first try transporting <s>it</s> him in a tram or bus to get accustomed to traveling with snowmen.

Comment: Welcome back User. I had hoped we were done with your questions, but apparently not. How did the Gold Bar and Bazooka go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [SAS Prohibited Items](https://www.flysas.com/en/uk/travel-info/baggage/prohibited-items/), the rules that apply are [those of the European Union](http://ec.europa.eu/transport/modes/air/security/info_travellers_en.htm) (emphasis mine):

> Under the current rules, you can carry as hand luggage, liquids in individual containers with a capacity not greater than 100 ml and contained in one transparent re-sealable plastic bag of a capacity not exceeding one liter. Liquids cover gels, aerosols, pastes, lotions, **liquid/solid mixtures and other items of similar consistency**, such as drinks, toothpaste, soups, syrups, perfumes, shaving foam, etc.

Since snow can readily be transformed into a liquid at room temperature, the above rules would apply. Only if your "snowman" is of a total volume of 100 mL or less, and is packed inside its own individual container contained inside a re-sealable plastic bag, would it be permitted. You will note that this arrangement leaves little room for equipment or additional material designed to keep the snowman cold enough to remain solid.

Attempting to transporting a snowman in a cooler would certainly not be permitted.

Comment: well, he could always check it in