# Can you take a coffee on a plane if you purchased it before security?

Tags: air-travel, uk, airport-security

I’m traveling to Paris from Edinburgh next week and confused whether I could get a frappuccino from Starbucks for the flight? I'm not sure if I could get one because of security?

Comment: It's a liquid so it won't make it past security.

Comment: you can't, but chances are it'll be warm and undrinkable after the security queue, boarding wait, etc ... Go to the airport 30 minutes before and enjoy your frapuccino ! Also, order it without cream on top.

Comment: I recommend using a freight plane. Make sure the barista inside brings his/her passport. :-)

Comment: Not really relevant to *this* question, but some airlines don't allow hot drinks to be brought on board (due to risk of spillage during boarding, the taxi, and climb out).

Comment: Surprised no one has yet discussed the feasibility of flash-freezing the coffee into coffee-cubes. (EDIT: oh I see they have on answer below)

Comment: Seriously, I bet there are plenty of Starbucks in both Edinburgh and Paris. The flight is what, an hour? I guess I am oldschool, but I think you can wait for one hour to get an overpriced "coffee" from a known tax-evader.

Comment: @dirkk that is beyond the point. Lots of people like a snack or drink while on a plane/train/car ride. Your opinion on Starbucks has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: There's a Starbucks in every single terminal at both Orly and CdG. So relax.

Answer (score 71):

A Frappuccino is considered a liquid. [For carry-on luggage](https://www.gov.uk/hand-luggage-restrictions), the UK only allows a single small resealable bag of liquids holding containers 100ml or less. Your Frappuccino would not qualify.

You cannot bring it through airport security. If there is a Starbucks past the security checkpoint, you can buy one there and bring it on board.

Comment: There are actually 8 Starbucks(!) in Paris Charles de Gaulle - looks the ones with *Zone réservée* next to them are the ones after security :) http://www.parisaeroport.fr/en/passengers/shops/shopping/store/starbucks-coffee

Comment: I think he's flying *from* Edinburgh *to* Paris.

Comment: @DJClayworth "I’m traveling to Paris from Edinburgh" you are correct

Comment: If you were to freeze the frappuccino before hand, would it still be considered a liquid? That would avoid the issue of warm beverages mentioned elsewhere as well. Might create other problems though.

Comment: @kirkpatt I've been told by security that ice is fine to bring, even though water is not. God help you if it melts while you're in line, though.

Comment: @kirkpatt [according to the answers here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27302/can-you-freeze-liquids-to-pass-security-checks) a frozen frappuccino might be considered a liquid either way. I've been told ice is OK, but the info seems murky when it comes to explicit drinks.

Comment: @DannyBeckett Unless you are flying QANTAS (and an unknown other set of airlines) where they do not trust the main security screening and have a 2nd check "at the gate" complete with XRay machine. I have seen people buy a drink from machines in the gate lounge and then have it confiscated as they board. | Flying China (or HK?) to NZ via Australia on a QANTAS flight I have seen the aircraft emptied (at Sydney) with travelers having to take all had luggage and then rechecked onto the plane via at the gate security. A drink taken off the plane would not have been allowed to be taken back on.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Where?? I've flown them 32 times in the past two months, never had an extra 'check' at the gate. BNE,SYD,MEL,CBR,ADL, and OOL.  Also it's [Qantas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qantas) now, no longer an acronym.  Might have been a China thing, not a Qantas thing.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Last time I checked, Qantas don't fly between Edinburgh and Paris :)

Comment: @DJClayworth Whoops, you're right, I read it the other way round :$ There is a Starbucks in Edinburgh Airport, but it's before security unfortunately. At least he can get one on the way back ;)

Comment: @MarkMayo If that's a China thing it must have happened in the last two years or so. Seems like it could be an airport specific thing - after all the infrastructure for checks has to be in place.

Comment: @Voo The QANTAS check used a portable machine in the boarding lounge. "Portable infrastructure" :-). I've also had it done by perhaps Air China. In each case it was leaving China.

Comment: @DannyBeckett  I dinna check, no need to, as " ... (and an unknown other set of airlines) .. " do :-)

Comment: @MarkMayo Humouously, the page you cite includes a QANTAS text in the box at right. All that means (arguably is that Qanta is all-caps in the logp but still not Q.A.N.T.A.S.

Answer (score 32):

You can't bring a coffee through security since, as the other answers say, it violates the rules for what liquids can go through security. However, you can buy a coffee after security and take it on the plane. It seems there's no Starbucks after security at Edinburgh but there's a Costa and a Caffe Nero ([map](http://www.edinburghairport.com/shopping-and-eating/find-shops-on-map)).

Indeed, even before the current restrictions, you couldn't bring coffees through security: I tried it once and had to bin it. They can't put your coffee through the X-ray machine because of the risk of spills; visual inspection won't detect any objects you might have hidden in it.

Comment: Your second paragraph is a great point!

Answer (score 11):

As the other answers have pointed out:

1. a frappuccino is a liquid;
2. Liquids are only allowed through security in containers holding less than 100ml, and all of those containers must fit in a single small resealable bag.

So the obvious solution is to take a large number of small bottles and decant your frappuccino  into portions smaller than 100ml (you'll probably find a tiny funnel helpful).

Give it a go and let me know how you get on. :)

Comment: This is a somewhat tongue in cheek answer, but might technically work. And I don't see the harm in trying; airport security staff are famous for their sense of humour...

Comment: @tardigrage - "sense of humour" in two very opposite senses. Which will apply to you on a given day deepends.

Comment: This should work, and it's actually my biggest beef with this idiotic system. If I come to security with a 500ml bottle of water, they make drink it or toss it. But if I bring the empty bottle, and the 500ml divided in five 100ml containers, now everything's fine. I can even refill my water bottle before I put my belt back.

Comment: Sounds like a market opportunity.  Make a "drink splitter" with several 100 ml bottles that is quick enough and easy enough to use that you can do so before security.  :D

Comment: @tardigrade Am I missing the sarcasm here or are you really serious? I have never met security staff which I would describe as even having a sense of humour. And this is actually ok, their job is not to be funny, but to check people for security. Where are these clown-esque security staff people?

Comment: @dirkk you are missing the sarcasm here. Although I fly a reasonable amount and don't think I've encountered friendlier security staff than at Glasgow (with Gatwick close behind). A sense of humour isn't incompatible with doing a good job, though.

Comment: I traveled with a large Pink Panther toy made from flexible-but-stiff rubber once (got it from some customer as a present, it was their mascot). It looked exactly like plastic explosives on the screen, they said, and there were some very alarmed looks on the faces. Until one of the guy got the pink guy out of my bag, they had a field day then. So, yes, humour does exist. Seldomly...

Comment: I done exactly what the answer suggested in Newark; actually, the security people recommended doing exactly that when they told me I couldn't take the liquid through security. I went back out through security, divided the liquid (honey in this case) into several small bottles, and then cleared the checkpoint unimpeded. This was in 2010, though.

Answer (score 10):

A somewhat facetious answer, but the only way to get your 100+ mL or hot drink through security is if YOU are the container.

Drink up in the queue and bin the cup at the top of the line, and everyone is happy - although you're more likely to need a "pitstop" somewhere before your destination.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

It's even become a 'newsworthy' checked item, and not just for the liquid content.

Firstly, it's liquid (even fraps), so while a tiny espresso or macchiato might be under the [100ml rule](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/liquids-rule), most coffees will not be allowed through.

Secondly, even if bought after security, [some Starbucks drinks are now being checked for explosives](https://www.wired.com/2012/09/tsa-moves-on-from-your-underwear-to-your-starbucks/)(!!).

Comment: my uk experience is that is not only does the product need to be under 100ml, but it needs to have the volume displayed on the container. So the espresso may not be allowed.

Comment: @MartinCapodici indeed, as in the linked rule website, it's the capacity of the container.  So,it 'might be under'.

Comment: I'm not sure how relevant TSA is to a flight from Edinburgh to Paris...

Comment: @PeterTaylor Europe uses the same liquid rules as the US so it doesn't make much difference.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, let me rephrase: I'm not sure how relevant TSA *going beyond the rules* is to a flight from Edinburgh to Paris.

Comment: I have personally seen the TSA testing the drinks of people as they boarded a flight and thought it was weird.  My response was to chug my drink before I queued up at the gate. And getting OT  I have also had bottles of water bought airside confiscated at the gate in BsAs, and found out that this is actually common around the world.

Comment: @PeterM interesting.  I just chucked a 500ml bottle of water to satisfy the TSA demons.  If I had known that I would have procured a 100ml bottle of vinegar (or human urine or something else) - labelled as water of course.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to bring a liquid you bought before security because of the 100ml liquid rule, as has been pointed out. However it's usually fine to bring a coffee you bought on the secure air side on to the plane. If you are concerned about spills you could bring an empty travel mug or similar with you and transfer your drink.

I've never flown from Edinburgh specifically but I regularly fly trans-Atlantic and the only time I've encountered an airport that didn't have a coffee shop air side (maybe not Starbucks specifically but some sort of purveyor of liquid caffeine) was when the terminal was being remodelled and all of the shops were closed.